# spring 3.0 type conversion from string in predefined format to a Map having key as the Enum type and value as any type

Tags: string, spring-mvc, dictionary, type-conversion

I am trying to create a generic convertor using Spring 3.0's Type Conversion feature for converting Strings in format **"<KEY2>:<VAL>,<KEY2>:<VAL2>,<KEY3>:<VAL3>"**
to a Map holding the key-value pairs *where key can be an Enum type and value can be of any user-defined or Java's inbuilt type*.

Below is the code I tried out.

Note: I am not good at using generics, so please bear with me if I have used generics in wrong way.

```
import java.lang.reflect.GenericDeclaration;
import java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterFactory;

/**
 * Converts a string in a format  
 * "&lt;KEY2&gt;:&lt;VAL&gt;,&lt;KEY2&gt;:&lt;VAL2&gt;,&lt;KEY3&gt;:&lt;VAL3&gt;" 
 * to a {@link Map} instance holding the key-value pairs <i>where key 
 * can be an Enum type and value can be of any type</i>.  
 * 
 * @author jigneshg
 *
 * @param <K>
 * @param <V>
 */
public class StringToMapConvertorFactory<V> implements ConverterFactory<String, Map<Enum<?>, V>> {

    private static final String COMMA = ",";
    private static final String COLON = ":";

    @Override
    public <T extends Map<Enum<?>, V>> Converter<String, T> getConverter(
            Class<T> targetType) {
        return new StringToMapConverter<T>(targetType);
    }

    private final class StringToMapConverter<T extends Map<Enum<?>, V>> implements Converter<String,T> {

        public StringToMapConverter(Class<T> targetType) {

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public T convert(String source) {
            checkArg(source);
            String[] keyValuePairs = source.split(COMMA);

            // value at index 0 is assumed as the key
            // value at index 0 is assumed as the value

            Map<Enum<?>,V> resultMap = new HashMap<Enum<?>, V>();

            String[] keyValueArr = null;
            String key = null;
            String value = null;
            for (String keyValuePair : keyValuePairs) {
                keyValueArr = keyValuePair.split(COLON);
                key = keyValueArr[0];
                value = keyValueArr[1];

                // TODO: How to specify the enumType here ??
                resultMap.put(Enum.valueOf(enumType, key.trim()), (V) value);
            }

            return resultMap; 
        }

        private void checkArg(String source) {
            // In the spec, null input is not allowed
            if (source == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("null source is in allowed");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I am stuck at how to specify the enum type when putting the key-value pair in **resultMap** in my code.

Also have I taken the correct approach to implement my requirement or there is a better way in which this can be achieved?

Thanks,
Jignesh

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [`GenericConverter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/GenericConverter.html) instead of `Converter`, and access key type as `TypeDescriptor.getMapKeyType()`.

Comment: Thanks axtavt for your guidance.I have achieved my requirement.Though I faced some problem after implementing GenericConverter I got that resolved and my solution I have posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934265/spring-3-0-custom-generic-converter-not-found-though-registered-error-no-matchi/8939555#8939555