# Spring doesn't see converter

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to use Converter in my Spring web application. Here is the code:

```
    public class RoleConverter implements Converter<String, Role> {
    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

    public Role convert(String id) {
        return roleService.getRole(Integer.parseInt(id));
    }
}
```

i've configured corresponding xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />

    <beans:bean id="conversionService"
          class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="converters">
            <beans:set>
                <beans:bean class="net.schastny.contactmanager.converters.RoleConverter"/>
            </beans:set>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

i also tried to use `class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean"`
instead

```
class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
```

but nothing helped. I always get an exception:

> Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [net.schastny.contactmanager.domain.Role] for property 'role': no
>   matching editors or conversion strategy found]

Please help me to recognize what I'm doing wrong. I've spend about 16 hours to fix the problem but nothing helped :(

**UPD**
Ok here is the short explanation what's going on: I have User class that contains Role class(one-to-many) and want to write jsp that allows create User with Role and I use dropdown for choosing the Role:

```
<form:form method="post" action="add" commandName="user">
Login:    <form:input path = "login" value = "" />
Password: <form:input path = "password" value = "" />
Select role:
             <form:select path="role">
                      <form:options items="${roleList}" itemValue="id"                itemLabel="description"/>
             </form:select>
    <input type="submit" value = "add">
</form:form>
```

so the idea is that after submitting I have Id of the Role so i want to get Role by its Id using Converter.
The code of method that causes exception is extremely easy:

```
@RequestMapping("/add")
public String home(@ModelAttribute User user) {


    System.out.println(user.getRole().getDescription());
    System.out.println(user.getLogin());
    System.out.println(user.getPassword());

    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

Comment: Show the code that triggers the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours banging my head against the wall I've found the solution. Here it is:
[spring 3.0 Custom generic converter not found though registered.Error: no matching editors or conversion strategy found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934265/spring-3-0-custom-generic-converter-not-found-though-registered-error-no-matchi)
I had the same problem. Hope someone will not spent 20 hours to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you print what 
    roleService.getRole(Integer.parseInt(id))
is returning . Is it returning a string which cannot be converted to a Role Object.